# Sorting a PIVOT table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a procedure that returns data from a PIVOT table.  I just need to sort this data so that the PIVOT displays the columns in a particular order.  I need them sorted by the "SortOrder" field in the Regions table.  Here's my script.  I don't actually need the sortorder field returned, I just need the columns sorted by sortorder.  Any help is appreciated

```
 CREATE TABLE #Temp  
(  
 Region VARCHAR(255),
 SortOrder INT,  
 Visible BIT  
)  

INSERT INTO #Temp  
SELECT R.Region, R.SortOrder, CASE WHEN (ISNULL(R_SR.RegionID,0) = 0 AND     ISNULL(R_SR_Serv.RegionID,0) = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Visible  
FROM ServiceRecord SR  
INNER JOIN Sites S ON SR.SiteID = S.SiteID  
INNER JOIN Regions R ON R.SiteID = S.SiteID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord R_SR ON R_SR.RegionID = R.RegionID AND R_SR.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord_Serv R_SR_Serv ON R_SR_Serv.RegionID = R.RegionID AND R_SR_Serv.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID  
WHERE SR.ServiceRecordID = @ServiceRecordID
 AND R.RegionID % 100 != 0  
 AND SR.IsDeleted = 0  
 AND SR.English = 1  
 AND SR.PostedMain = 1  
ORDER BY SR.ServiceRecordID, R.SortOrder

DECLARE @RegionList varchar(2000),@SQL varchar(max)  
SELECT @RegionList = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QuoteName(Region) FROM #Temp ORDER BY ',' + QuoteName(Region) FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  

SET @SQL='  
SELECT  
   A.*
FROM   
   (  
   SELECT  
     Region,
     CAST(Visible AS INT) AS Visible  
  FROM #Temp
   ) B
   PIVOT(MAX(Visible) FOR Region IN (' + @RegionList + ')) A
   ORDER BY SortOrder;';  

EXEC (@SQL);
```

In the initial select (before PIVOT), I get the following table (this is the order I want them pivoted in.

```
London and Middlesex    0
Oxford and Norfolk  1
Elgin   0
Huron and Perth 1
Grey and Bruce  0
```

After the pivot, this is my result

```
Elgin   Grey and Bruce  Huron and Perth London and Middlesex    Oxford and Norfolk
0           0           1               0                        1
```

I am trying to have the columns sorted in the same order as the table shows before the pivot (London and Middlesex first, Oxford and Norfolk 2nd, etc)

Comment: If you include the `SortOrder` column in your `select from #temp` do you get an error?  What does the result show?

Comment: if I add SortOrder to the #temp table, it messes up the PIVOT and rather than getting 1 row back, I get multiple rows (1 for each SortOrder value)

Comment: Can you post the create table statement, some sample data for each table and then the desired result?  Or create a http://sqlfiddle.com with your existing structure/data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the final columns to be ordered then you should be able to add the `ORDER BY SortOrder` in your query that gets the `@regionList` so you will change the code to the following:

```
DECLARE @RegionList varchar(2000),@SQL varchar(max)  
SELECT @RegionList = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QuoteName(Region) 
                            FROM #Temp 
                            GROUP BY Region, SortOrder
                            ORDER BY SortOrder  --- add the SortOrder here
                            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Your current code is ordering the data by the Region so it is alphabetical.  You need to implement the SortOrder in this list.

Comment: thanks, that worked perfect!  I was trying to sort that section, but I wasn't doing it right.  thanks again

Comment: Glad it is working, once you posted the data it was easier to see how to fix it.